# Tcl/Tk Shell error running Spawn/bin/bash

Tags: tcl, expect

I have written several shell scripts with tcl/tk and I run it on the machine with the user group, when I give it to another user with different machine or from another IP it gives error.

Spawn/bin/bash

But if I run it from my machine where I wrote it, it  runs correctly.

The header is so defined.

```
#! / Usr/bin/expect -f
#
```

Can you tell me that I have not added or am missing so that it can run from any pc and any user?

Comment: You will need to show the actual script and the actual error message to have any hope of getting help.

Comment: Is it just `/ Usr/bin/expect` being supposed to be `/usr/bin/expect`? No space and no capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

From the question you have posted, it looks like to me one or more of following issues. Apart from that the real problem looks to me is in /bin/bash. Check manually once in the machine where the problem lies.

First check manually from other machine where the issue is present. Checking is easy.

```
which expect
expect
spawn /bin/bash
```

Have you got the error? Also check if there is -

1. Difference in expect version
2. Permission issue
3. Have you considered the scenario where you are prompted for storing RSA key? Relevant in case you are connecting to other machines from the host you are running the program.

Thank,
Mr. Bordoloi